# How to invert the values of a logical jagged array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, math, matrix, jagged-arrays

Good afternoon, I have a c# jagged array with true and false values (or 0's and 1's) and I want to reverse the values like:

```
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
1 0 0 1
```

to became:

```
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0
```

Is there an easy way to do it not looping it? something like !myJaggedArray??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no built-in operation for inverting an array like that, but you can use LINQ to do the inversion without explicit loops:

```
var res = myJaggedArray.Select(a => a.Select(n => 1-n).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

The `1-n` trick is a common way of replacing zeros with ones and ones with zeros without using conditional execution.

Comment: what you guys think will be faster to work with (lopps, operations etc), a bool[][] or int[][]? what about bitarrays?

Comment: @Ralstlin If using `BitArray`s is an option, you could do it with a single array of `BitArray`s, and use the `Not` operation to do inversion really quickly. This would be the most economical option for 2D matrices of moderate to large size.

Comment: instead of using `1-n` you can use `1^n`

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, Looking into it, i found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471759/is-bitarray-faster-in-c-sharp-for-getting-a-bit-value-than-a-simple-conjuction-w and seems that an array of bools is faster. I really need to be as fast as posible because I am working on Unity3D and with a matrix of bools i want to create a 3D space as fast as posible. I use an Spiral algorithm that run over the matrix to get the minimum number of squares and his position and with that information I want to generate 3D vertices to draw a Mesh. So speed is really important here.

Comment: I did a test with bool[][], vs bitArray[]  size: 10.000x10.000
BoolJagged Creation: 580ms
BoolJagged Loop: 510ms
BoolJagged Random Access: 16025ms
BitArray Creation: 2059ms
BitArray Loop: 1534ms
BitArray Random Access: 15947ms

Not a bit difference in 100.000.000 Random access

Comment: @Ralstlin The difference in memory use should be quite high: `BitArray` should be 8 times smaller than an array of `bool`s.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i will be modifying the 3D objects in runtime, i am not sure if 8 times smaller is better than 3 times faster, when i will have 2-3 100x100, 50-60 5x20 and 100-150 1x10   Thats is like 37k-38k bools

Comment: Note that this creates a bunch of new arrays and puts them in a new "outer" array. Another goal could be to reverse all values in-place, so that people holding references to the original jagged array could "see" the change. The question was not clear which was desired.

Answer (score 8):

There is no built-in function, but you can use LINQ.

```
int[][] input = new[]
{
  new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
  new[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
  new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
  new[] { 1, 0, 0, 1 }
};
int[][] output = input.Select(row => row.Select(value => value == 1 ? 0 : 1).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

For logical values:

```
bool[][] input = new[]
{
  new[] { true,  true,  true,  true },
  new[] { false, true,  true,  false },
  new[] { true,  true,  true,  true },
  new[] { true,  false, false, true }
};
bool[][] output = input.Select(row => row.Select(value => !value).ToArray()).ToArray();
```